# difference between "enum" and "in" in model description

Tags: mysql, sails.js, waterline

Is there any difference between these two model definitions? They both seem to work and I can't find anything in the docs.

```
module.exports = {
    schema: true,

    attributes: {
         state: {
           type: 'string',
           enum: [
               'requested',
               'rejected',
               'accepted'
            ]
          }, 
    }
}
```

And this one:

```
module.exports = {
    schema: true,

    attributes: {
         state: {
           type: 'string',
           in: [
               'requested',
               'rejected',
               'accepted'
            ]
          }, 
    }
}
```

I saw particlebanana recommend someone use "in" here [sails-mysql schema datatypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564820/sails-mysql-schema-datatypes), but enum seems to work the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be same, based on this reference [Waterline Docs](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes)

And this [source code](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/blob/master/lib/waterline/core/validations.js)

```
// use the Anchor `in` method for enums
  if(prop === 'enum') {
    self.validations[attr]['in'] = attrs[attr][prop];
    return;
  }
```

Comment: In Sails 1.x, the validation is called `isIn` (not just `in` anymore).