# Custom primary key, foriegn key creation and query execution in sails

Tags: mysql, sails.js

I am newbie on **SailsJS Sails-MySQL**. I am not able to create custom primary key and foriegn key in the model and also how to execute query in sails. If you have any solution or even links to the tutorials that can help me out with basic sails syntax and process that would be great help.

Comment: I found the answer this is in following questions answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564820/sails-mysql-schema-datatypes